# Android - PushBots: device doesn't receive notifications after changing package name

Tags: android, push-notification, cloud

I changed the package name of my application and now I doesn't receive any push notification. The devices are registered on the pushbots site.

Before I made these changes it worked perfect.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

It must likely uses Android GCM or some other similar implementation which relies on a signature hash AND the package name.

Comment: In the google cloud console I created a new project and they asked me for the sha1 hash value. I wrote down the value which I received by exporting my android application.

Comment: for the pushbots sender id I used the project number from the cloud console (not the project id)

Comment: In the console you should specify, when adding an android certificate, the SHA1 hash followed by ";your.package.name" without the quotes.

Comment: I tried with the sha1 value which I get from the console, but I still don't receive any notifications

Comment: do I need the project number or the project id for the pushbots sender id?

Comment: this happened to me. I think that pushbot is buggy